# adding File priveleges to user in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I have something like this in phpmyadmin
[image]

so I need to add the FILE privelege so that I can get the data dump through console, I am logged in as root.Through PHPmyadmin if i click on Edit privileges and then select FILE and save it says
[image]

Even through console I tried this

```
  GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO root@DBSERVERNAME IDENTIFIED BY abc2013;

and it says
```

ERROR 1470 (HY000): String 'root@DBSERVERNAME' is too long for user name (should be no longer than 16)

Not sure what I am missing,I only have access as root user.

Comment: your login don't have the enough privileges to enable the access

Comment: @Sundar this is the default database created at amazon, so you are saying there is no way that I can get FILE permission?

Comment: an account can only grant the permissions it's been granted itself. `super` is not "all" privileges: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237475/cannot-grant-privileges-to-mysql-database check this for additional informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable management and prevent users from breaking some of the management systems within RDS. You are restricted from access certain permissions (FILE and SUPER are not given to users).

FILE permissions wouldn't make sense anyway since you don't have local access to the RDS instance to load files in the first place.

Comment: I have access to master user and master password as well, but I am unable to login through phpmyadmin, though I am able to login through bash

Comment: @user1765876 Just because you call your user account `root` on RDS does not mean you have root privileges.  The RDS account gives you a subset of privileges compared to what you would have on a standard system.  I would actually suggest that you not use `root` as your username as this connotes more privilege than you have.

Comment: @user1765876 The only user that gets all permissions is `rdsadmin`. You do not get access to this account. When you set a master account in RDS, you can an account with most, but not all of the priviliges.

Comment: @datasage I am able to get file privelege on root user, I have access to adsadmin ,and I can login through bash

Comment: @user1765876 I don't think you are connecting to the same mysql server  that your question indicates.

Comment: @datasage so I can get that we cannot get FILE permission in rds as a user?

Comment: @user1765876 That is correct, RDS does not allow `FILE` permission. You don't have SSH access to the RDS instance anyway.

Comment: @datasage Hence this query is not possible in php then ?
SELECT * from myTable
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/querydump.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Comment: @user1765876 Correct. You could probably find a client that will provide similar functionality. As long as the client generates the csv instead of the server you will be fine.