# Grant privileges to an existing user in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, privileges

Trying to grant privileges to an *existing* database user using

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON myschema.* TO 'OptimusPrime'@'cybertron';
```

But I keep getting

```
1410, 'You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT'
```

I'm stumped since I'm *certain* that user OptimusPrime exists in the database (!). I verified it using

```
select * from mysql.user;
```

and indeed, OptimusPrime is there. I'm stumped. Anyone as a clue on why I keep getting this? I'm not trying to create a new user

EDIT: I'm using the root user

EDIT2: Tried doing that to root user. Getting same error. I'll try to reinstall the server. Something is fishy. I'll update once I've done that

Comment: check your current user, maybe your user doesn't have access to grant other users permissions, are using a privileged user?

Comment: I'm using root user. The user has created the entire db schema just before trying this statement

Comment: You say OptimusPrime is there, but is that OptimusPrime@cybertron? Actually show us the results of that query so that we can help you.

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237475/cannot-grant-privileges-to-mysql-database the accepted answer might help.

Comment: Thanks @mamounothman, I checked and I'm using root user and root does have grant options so I'm not sure this is the case

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 can you be more specific? The users table is big and I can't post all of it here

Comment: Then make a new database with just the one user in it, reproduce the issue, then show the output. Or copy this one and remove the unrelated items. Or show only the output pertaining to this user. We cannot help you if all we see is a normal `GRANT` statement and a normal `SELECT` query. And if you just "reinstall the server" then you may never know what happened (and/or you may cause other problems).

Answer (score 2):

To execute this command, you need to execute the sql query as admin, or with user granted to execute a `GRANT` query.

You can connect with `root` user, and try to execute

```sql
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON myschema.* TO 'OptimusPrime'@'cybertron';
```

and the result will be better.

Comment: Actually, I'm already connecting with root. It is a part of a script that creates the schema. At the end of it (to avoid any further root-user statements) I want to grant permissions to a regular user

Comment: You have edited the permissions of your root user before ? Or is a fresh installation ?

Comment: I'm not sure that you mean: edited the root user? no. I'm trying to edit OptimusPrime. And yeah, I think he's been edited before

Comment: Ok, what's your MySQL server version ?

Comment: SELECT @@version; -- 8.0.18

Comment: Thanks, silly question but, the user OptimusPrime already exists ?

Comment: Yes, he exists. I *think* he exists for the schema, but unsure how to verify that

Comment: It strange, because the root user have all privileges by default... Have tried to execute this query (just adding the grant option to your root user) ? 
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*your password root*' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: Tried. Strangely, I get the same error. I think I'll reinstall the server, this starts looking very strange. I'll post an update once I've done that

Comment: May be the force be with you.